# Input not supported (AREA 51) PC GAME

Tags: windows-7

If i open AREA 51 and the screen be black and saying "input not supported"
Please tell me the problem and how to fix it. ;(
I use window 7.

Answer (score 0):

The game is trying to set your monitor to a resolution that it does not support, either it is too low or too high a resolution for your display.

Chances are that you have copied the game from a system with a 1920x1080 monitor and are now using it on a system with a lower resolution monitor.

From  [PCGamingWiki](http://pcgamingwiki.com/wiki/Area_51_(2005)) it looks like the video configuration is stored in a file called `UserVConfig.ini`. you can either trawl through that file looking for what looks like the resolution and set it to be what your display is capable of, or you can just delete that file and the game will either automatically detect your resolution or will just fall back to a lower resolution.